# Segmentation Fault when Assigning Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, sfml

When I try to init a class that has class pointer variables to other class objects, I get segmentation a segmentation fault. Example code snippet below.

I've tried initializing the variables with the 'new' keyword to empty classes first, as well as manually using malloc before assigning, and tried just assigning the variables without any fancy allocation and nothing works.

```c
// Caller
void Application::run()
{
    Network network(this);
    network.start();
}

// Seg fault here, at the line that assigns window
Network::Network(Application *app)
{
    application = new Application();
    window = new sf::RenderWindow();
        application = app;
    window = app->window;
}

// Header for Network
class Network 
{
    public:
        Application* application;
        sf::RenderWindow* window;
    // Functions
    Network(Application *app);
        void start();
        void networkLoop();
    private:
    protected:
};

// Header for Application
class Application 
{
    public:
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    Theme* theme;
    // Functions
    Application();
    void run();
    private:
    protected:
};

// Main
#include "application.h"
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main()
{
    XInitThreads();
    Application* app;
    app->run();
}
```

I'm pretty new at using C++, so forgive me for obvious memory errors. I've tried searching for a solution but nothing I've found has worked. I accept a pointer to Application as input for the constructor because I want the same instance of RenderWindow and Application to be held across other objects.

EDIT: I feel really dumb but I altered `main()` to create `Application` with `Application app` instead of `Application* app` and it seems to have fixed it. But still: could someone explain why that works and using a pointer does not?

Comment: In `Application::run()` it calls it with itself, `Network network(this)`.

Comment: You're asking why allocating it it in `main()` works and not in `Network`?

Comment: I was confused why I had to use a `new` in main(), or could it just be `Application` without a pointer?

Comment: @Ash You should rarely need `new`. `Application app;` is the clean solution and the same is true for `sf::RenderWindow* window;` in `Application`, which should be `sf::RenderWindow window;`. And the two `new` in the constructor of `Network` shouldn't be there. I don't understand why `Network` has a pointer to `sf::RenderWindow` in the first place, when this is accessible through `application`.

Comment: Pointers and the like are the **one** thing I can never nail into my brain to understand. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Ash Only use pointers when something refers to something else, but is not part of it and then don't use `new` on it, but rather assign it to the thing that was already created somewhere else. For example a window is a part of the application and should be destroyed when the application is destroyed. Therefore `window` in `Application` should not be a pointer.

Comment: A pointer is simply a variable whose value points at some other object. For example, the issue with `main` is that there is no `Application` object around for `app` to point at.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `main()`

```
int main()
{
    XInitThreads();
    Application* app;
    app->run();
}
```

You need to use `new` here and allocate your `Application`:

```
int main()
{
    XInitThreads();
    Application* app = new Application(...);
    app->run();
}
```

However, **don't** do it in `Network`. That will create a memory leak. Do this instead:

```
Network::Network(Application *app)
{
    application = app;
    window = app->window;
}
```

---

Edit:

> could someone explain why that works and using a pointer does not?

So, pointers do not allocate any memory by themselves. They are simply pointers. They hold addresses. They don't allocate memory by themselves to allow things like this:

```
int a =0;
int *b = &a; // holds address of a
```

If pointers allocated data here, it could cause a memory leak or other things. Thus, if you want to hold a new object independent of other variables, you need to use `new` or some smart pointer:

```
int* c = new int; // c holds an int independent of a or b
```

Thus, if you simply do something like this:

```
int* d;
```

`d` has no memory allocated at its position by itself. It is a placeholder that can hold any address. It can hold an existing address, or a new address. But it needs to store some valid address before you can use it.

If you want to create an instance of `Application`, you either have to allocate it with `new` or, as others have pointed out, not even use a pointer at all, which is actually the recommended course of action:

```
int main()
{
    XInitThreads();
    Application app;
    app.run();
}
```

Comment: I *just* altered my question that I found that, sorry to waste your time providing a better solution. Would you mind if I ask why I cannot assign it via pointer? What's the difference between `new` and a regular `Application` ?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your edit, the difference between

```
Application* app;
```

and

```
Application app;
```

is what gets allocated and constructed, and what does not.

In the first example, the compiler sets aside enough space in the stack to hold a pointer, but does not set aside any space for what it might be pointing to - you need to do that manually with `new`. This was why your program did not work - you had space for a pointer, but when you de-referenced that pointer with `->`, there was no `Application` waiting at the other end. You told it to find an `Application` and take the `window` property and store it somewhere else, but that `window` property had never been created.

In the second example, the compiler sets aside enough space for a full `Application` object, and calls the constructor for you. So when you de-reference the pointer this time, there is an `Application` waiting there to be used.

---

I want to add another piece of information. In the first example, pointers aren't objects, and don't have constructors to be called, so if you don't assign a value to them, their initial values are essentially random - whatever was in stack at the time. So not only was your pointer not pointing to an `Application`, it probably wasn't even pointing to a usable memory location, which is why you got a segmentation fault.

Comment: Technical nag: C++ is perfectly happy without a stack. If you can figure out how to do it, you can implement the Automatic datastore with fairy dust.

Comment: "*pointers aren't objects*": Technically pointers are considered objects in C++ as well. They are however non-class type objects and so you are right that their default-initialized value will be indeterminate.

Comment: It's easier to [list what isn't an object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) in C++ than what is an object. Irritating that the same term is used two different ways.

Comment: Pointers aren't objects in the traditional OOP-sense, which seems like a more rational thing to talk about than C++ objects.